# Turn jpeg into high poly model

Tags: javascript, python, 3d, polymodel

I am looking for something in maybe javascript or python which can take a jpeg and turn it into a poly model based on the image?

For this I will be looking at transforming an portrait image of a person and produce a semi 3D image. (I will write a separate script to fill in the spaces)

Any help or a push in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd say google, but that would be obvious

Comment: I was unable to find anything on Google, that is why I have posted to a programmers question and answer site. Thank you for your insightful comment though, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the package [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/index.html) could solve your somewhat unclear question. It comes with good image manipulation methods.